# I had been training for years before

Tags: tense, past-tense, past-perfect, past-simple

I'm not sure why, but I don't really feel like

> I had been training for years **before** *I could do that jump*

---

I know how the past-perfect works, and for example

> I had been training for years **when** *I finally did that jump*

sounds perfect.

So, do you think the first sentence is correct? I found an example for *could* that says:

> She ​**walked** off **before** *I could say anything*.

Does it use the past-simple (*walked*) because the action is clearly before, or because it's actually describing a situation that happened at the same time?

Maybe if it had been *had walked*, it would have meant that she wasn't there when he almost started to talk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sentences are correct.

> I had been training for years before I could do that jump

To my ear and brain, the focus in the sentence is on the time it took to train for the jump.

> I had been training for years when I finally did that jump

Whereas in this sentence, it is more on the event of finally performing the jump.